# Symfony 3 - render_false form not working

Tags: symfony

I'm working on a project in Symfony 3, and I have a problem with the render_false.

I have to do a dynamic form. Form's fields will depend on the object's values.
And there is a lot of possibilities.

I do all this treatment on the controller, and I return an array with all the fields I have to display.

Then, I display those fields on Twig. But, I don't want to render the rest.
So I use  the option : `{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}`

But Symfony returns me

> "Type error: Argument 1 passed to Bill::setEntreeAutomateInput() must
>   be of the type string, null given"

I have the impression that Symfony fills my field with null when it's "", there is a possibility to remediate on that ?

Here is my edit.html.twig :

```
    {{ form_row(form.save, {'attr': {'class': 'ui button'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
    {{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

Thanks you very much all

Edit : If I use

```
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

It works, but of course, it's not what i want to do because it displays all the fields

Edit 2 : If it can helps, in the debugger, the controller fails when i try to submit the request with :

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $em->persist($bill);
  $em->flush();
```

It fails at the first line

Comment: Is it when you create or edit your entity? Does your entity has setter with nullable params? (like `setEntreeAutomateInput(string $param = null)`

Comment: It's when I edit the entity, i don't create an entity by a form. And the setter isn't nullable.
I want to add that when i use {{ form_rest(form) }}, I can edit without problem and it is saved in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If it can helps someone. It's not a clean solution, but, for the moment, i will use that.

You can use :

```
  <div id="divCheckbox" style="display: none;">
         {{ form_rest(form) }}
    </div>
```

It will hide fields that you wanted to hide, and you will be able to save your form.